# I get no HTTP or DNS traffic in wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am trying to analyze the traffic from a smartphone, through wireshark, but when I enter the HTTP or DNS filter, it shows nothing.
The network I am analyzing is WPA2/PSK. I put the PSK key in Protocols/IEEE 802.11. I also captured the handshake of the target device.
If I set the ARP filter, it shows data normally. I don't know why it doesn't work with HTTP and DNS filters. I already tried opening applications and web pages on the phone, but it shows nothing.
Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Are you setting a capture filter or a display filter? A capture filter may not work because the data is possibly still encrypted at that phase.

Comment: @DanielB I do not use the capture filter, only the display filter.

Comment: 1) Are you capturing in normal or "Monitor" mode? 2) Are you seeing _any_ unicast 802.11 data frames from the phone (i.e. not counting the broadcast frames like ARP queries)? 3) Have you captured the phone's WPA2 handshake for this session? 4) Are you sure the phone is using PSK and not WPA3/SAE?

Comment: @user1686 1) I am capturing in monitor mode. 2) Yes, I also see 802.11 data frames. 3) Yes, I captured the handshake. 4) I'm not sure, I guess it uses WPA2/PSK, the phone is a samsung galaxy A33 5g.

Comment: Your phone's radio is probably 2x2 AC. If your AP is also at least a 2x2 AC device, is your sniffer radio also 2x2 AC? If not, you won't be able to receive any packets sent using those modulation schemes.

Comment: @Spiff The wifi usb adapter I am using is the tp-link Archer t2u Plus which is compatible with 2.4 and 5GHz.

Comment: @yellowdog The TP-Link Archer T2U Plus is a 1x1. It doesn't have the second radio chain hardware it would need to see 2x2 MIMO transmissions. If your phone and AP are both 2x2 MIMO (or better), then your T2U just doesn't have the hardware to see their MIMO transmissions. You're probably just seeing multicasts, which APs must send at lower rates so that everyone, even 1x1 devices, can see them.

Comment: @Spiff Ok, I understand, but why if I analyze the traffic of my pc in the same way, it shows HTTP and DNS traffic correctly?( with the same wifi adapter)

Comment: @yellowdog If your PC's Wi-Fi adapter is the same 1x1 as your sniffer, then it can't do the 2x2 MIMO transmissions that your sniffer can't see.

Comment: @Spiff On my PC I am using the TL-WN722N wifi adapter

Comment: @yellowdog That TL-WN722N is also a 1x1. So it only has hardware capable of transmitting signals that your 1x1 sniffer radio can receive.

Comment: @Spiff So, this problem is because my phone uses 2x2 and the adapter I use to sniff in wireshark is 1x1? If so, which wifi adapter do you recommend for sniffing modern phones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141252/discussion-between-spiff-and-yellowdog).